# Sum a Column in a jTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am having a problem trying to get values from a column within a jTable and sum them up. This is the code I have so far:

```
public void saveTable(){
    for(int i = 0; i < jTable2.getRowCount(); i++){
        int total = 0;
        int Amount = (int) jTable2.getValueAt(i, 5);
        total = Amount+total;
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

However I keep getting ClassCastException Errors specifically:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:      java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at my.rcsv1.accounting.DraftInvoice.saveTable(DraftInvoice.java:851)
```

Which is referring to the line of code:

```
int Amount = (int) jTable2.getValueAt(i, 5);
```

What do I need to do in order to get this to work?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't cast. Parse the value with `Integer.parseInt`

Comment: Like this?
    `int Amount = Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 5));`

Comment: Yes, do it like that.

Comment: Then I get an error saying Object cannot be converted to String?

Comment: Why use Strings in the first place for numeric values? I say get rid of the strings and add the values to the table/model as integers

Comment: Try with `int Amount = Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 5).toString())`

Comment: How are you putting values in to the table? If you put in numbers, you should take out numbers. If you're putting in strings, you'll take out strings again.

Are you using a table model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int Amount = Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 5)+"");
```

Will do the thing

Comment: Awesome that works when the value is a plain int. Although when inputting data into the table the value in that column gets changed into a decimal. Anyway around that?

Comment: `double d = Double.parseDouble(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 5)+""); int Amount = (int) d;`

Comment: Is there no way to stop it from getting rounded off?

Comment: It doesn't matter if your input are only the integer numbers. But if you want work with real numbers you just can't store it as integer without rounding.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting to a primitive data type, you should be parsing.

Try this:

`int amount = Integer.parseInt(jTable2.getValueAt(i, 5));`

Also you shouldn't start variable names with a capital ie `int Amount` should be `int amount`

Answer (score 1):

The exception says you stored a String in that column.

You might do in better style by using the data model, `jTable.getModel()`. But this is it:

```
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < jTable2.getRowCount(); i++){
        int amount = Integer.parseInt((String) jTable2.getValueAt(i, 5));
        total += amount;
    }
    System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the method through the constructor

```
public moneyManager() {
        initComponents();
        getSum();
        table_update();//table gets updated when records added
        getSum();
    }
```

Method Implementation

```
 private void getSum() {
        
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i =0;i<jTable1.getRowCount();i++){
            sum = sum +Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
            //here i is the row wise iteration and 2 is the column number of my 
              calculation attribute
        }
        //JlableTotal is where I want to display the total
        JlableTotal.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
   }
```